# JPA how to aggregate columns in a join

Tags: jpa, join, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to implement a query like this in JPA:

```
SELECT 
    ta.field_aggr_1, 
    ta.field_aggr_2,
    MIN(tb.date_inv) AS min_date_inv,
    MAX(tb.date_inv) AS max_date_inv

FROM table_a ta 
INNER JOIN table_b tb ON ta.idB = tb.id

GROUP BY 
    ta.field_aggr_1, 
    ta.field_aggr_2
```

The key point is the `MIN` and `MAX` functions that apply in one column of a joined table.

I've created the entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_a")
public class EntityA extends Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="field_aggr_1")
    private String field_aggr_1;    

    @Column(name="field_aggr_2")
    private String field_aggr_2;    

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idB")
    private EntityB entityB;

    // Getters & Setters & HashCode & equals & toString 
}

@Entity
@Table(name="table_b")
public class EntityB extends Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="date_inv")
    private String date_inv;    

    // Getters & Setters & HashCode & equals & toString  
}
```

And in the service I want to create query:

```
EntityManager em = ...;
Root<EntityA> root = criteriaQuery.from(EntityA.class);
EntityType<EntityA> type = this.em.getMetamodel().entity(EntityA.class);
Join<EntityA, EntityB> join = root.join(type.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("entityB", EntityB.class));

List<Selection<?>> fields = new ArrayList<Selection<?>>();

// grouping fields
fields.add(root.<EntityA>get("field_aggr_1"));
fields.add(root.<EntityA>get("field_aggr_2"));
```

I've managed to include fields from the joined table,

```
fields.add(join.<EntityB>get("date_inv"));
```

BUT I haven't succeed in implement the min aggregation.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: whats wrong with "cb.min(...)" where cb is CriteriaBuilder? You'll find that in JPA criteria examples on the web

Comment: Why don't you use JPQL?

Comment: Hi @NeilStockton, thank you for our comment. I've tried to use cd.min(...) but I need an Expression and I do not know how to extract an Expression from a join, where the data that I need is.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, could you be more specific? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jherranzm if your question is about an exception, it should contain the exception stack trace, and the code producing that exception. I don't know how I can be more specific. JPQL is the standard JPA query language. It looks like SQL, and allows defining and executing queries in a much much simpler and readable way than the criteria API. So, why do you use the Criteria API, and not JPQL?

Comment: you aren't extracting an expresstion from a join, you're extracting it from the CANDIDATE (root). So root.get("field_aggr_1") ... you already did it! As already said JPA Criteria tutorials show this, here's one  http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/jpql_criteria.html

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, thank you for your comment. My question is not about an exception. I'm trying to code this but my IDE (Eclipse) informs me that there is an error. It says that I need an Expression but I do not know how extract it from a join. I'm trying to use Criteria API because it allows me to divide and reuse parts of the selects and the grouping part and allows me to organize better the code, or I least thats what I think...

Comment: Hi @NeilStockton, what I neet to implement is ", MIN(tb.date_inv) as min_date_inv". I think that I haven't managed to explain it clearly. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve the question. First, I needed to have one more "root" and one more "entityType" for the joined entity:

```
Root<EntityB> rootB = criteriaQuery.from(EntityB.class);
EntityType<EntityB> typeB = this.em.getMetamodel().entity(EntityB.class);
```

With these, now I can do what I needed:

```
fields.add(builder.least(rootB.get(typeB.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("date_inv", String.class))));
fields.add(builder.greatest(rootB.get(typeB.getDeclaredSingularAttribute("date_inv", String.class))));
```

Hope that it helps someone!